# How can I define a STL compatible input iterator without interhitance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, iterator

I am trying to learn C++ and would like to understand iterators better. To that end, I tried to write an STL compatible iterator for a custom class (called `StrBlob` which holds strings, defined in the wonderful [C++ Primer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)). Eventually, the following iterator definition worked:

```
class StrBlob::iterator
    : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,  // iterator_category
                           std::string,              // value_type
                           std::string,              // difference_type
                           const std::string*,       // pointer
                           std::string               // reference
                           > {
   public:
    iterator() : curr(0) {}
    iterator(StrBlob& a, size_t sz = 0) : wptr(a.data), curr(sz) {}
    iterator& operator++();  // prefix operators
    iterator& operator--();
    iterator operator++(int);  // postfix operators
    iterator operator--(int);
    std::string& operator*() const;
    std::string* operator->() const;
    bool operator==(const iterator& b) const { return curr == b.curr; }
    bool operator!=(const iterator& b) const { return curr != b.curr; }

   private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> check(std::size_t,
                                                    const std::string&) const;
    std::weak_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> wptr;
    std::size_t curr;
};
```

Initially I tried for a long time in vain to design the iterator with the right type definitions myself. This didn't work, so I simply provided an inheritance to `std::iterator` as mentioned in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).

Can I write the class without inheritance at all?  If so, how would I have to rewrite the code above?

(I tried to understand Stackoverflow answers to related questions about iterator design but they were a bit to abstract for me.)

Comment: An iterator is a pointer to an element. ++ on the iterator must point to the next element. If this is, say, a continuous stream, it's simply ++ing the raw pointer. If it's a list, it's getting the next element. It's an abstraction where the underlying details are hidden.

Comment: [std::iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) is deprecated in C++17, and only provides typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is bugged, `std::string` is not a suitable difference type (`difference_type` is the difference between two iterators so normally its `std::ptrdiff_t`), nor is `std::string` a suitable reference type (should be `std::string&`).

Here's the correct typedefs, you can use these instead of inheritance.

```
typedef std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
typedef std::string value_type;
typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
typedef std::string* pointer;
typedef std::string& reference;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write the class without inheritance at all? If so, how would I have to rewrite the code above?

Yes, `std::iterator` (deprecated in C++17), only provides typedef.

So you can add those typedef yourself instead of using inheritance.

```cpp
class StrBlob::iterator
{
public:
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = std::string;
    using difference_type = std::string;// should be `std::ptrdiff_t`
    using pointer = const std::string*; // const should probably be dropped, unless you do const_iterator
    using reference = std::string; // should be std::string&

// ...
};
```